# Can't login using python requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to login to https://app.icarus.flights/ using python but get error "Incorrect username or password". What I do wrong (email and pass are correct). Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://api.icarus.flights/login'
payload = {
    "email": "some@email.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
headers_ = {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers_)

print(r.text)
```

{"message":"Incorrect username or password"}

Comment: did you try `json=json.dumps(payload)`?

Comment: also maybe `"username": "some@email.com"` instead of `"email"`?

Comment: is there any documentation about this `login` endpoint? might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just tried to add json=json.dumps(payload) after "playload" and try to use 'username'. It doesn't change nothing: "Incorrect username or password"

Comment: that's too bad, not sure what's wrong then. Would really help to have some sort of documentation about this login endpoint, so we can be sure what you are sending is on the correct format